# How can I combine multiple list with key values into a single dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and using data frames in general.

I'm working with selenium and capture some information from a linkedin profile. I created a list to store names, another to store location, then created a list exp with key values job, company, date, job_location, description, and another ed list with key values college and degree.

So for example:

```
name = Lisa
location = us
exp = {job : software engineer
      company : amazon
      date : 03/12
      job location : seattle
      description : worked as a software dev
       }
ed = { college : standford
       degree : computer science
      }
```

Something to note is that the exp and ed could contain several values for one value in the name/location list.

For example Lisa can have several jobs like software engineering and qa job which took place in different companies and different locations. Similarly, Lisa can have two degrees from different colleges.

So for example:

```
name = Lisa
location = us
exp = {job : software engineer, technical lead
      company : amazon, spectrum
      date : 03/12, 11/27
      job location : seattle, california
      description : worked as a software dev, manager
       }
ed = { college : standford, carleton
       degree : computer science, human resources
      }
```

Ideally, I want to store this as a dataframe to later download into a csv where column contains the list data and the row is the key/list so that it looks like things

```
              column 1    column 2
name          Lisa        mark 
location      us          us
job           se          se
company       amazon      amazon
date          3/12        3/12
job_location  seattle     seattle
description   worked as... worked
college       standford    standford
degree        cs          cs
```

In summary, I want to take 4 lists (name, location, exp, ed), two of which are dictionary list (exp and ed) and make it into a single dataframe

I searched this on google and found this geek4geeks tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-concatenate-two-or-more-pandas-dataframes/

My attempt was:
profile_dict = pd.concat([profile_intro, exp, ed], axis=1, join='inner')

But I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
    python-BaseException
```

Which makes me think that I'm missing on how to get the dictionary values into the dataframe instead of trying to get the keys which is not allowed and or not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use the = sign in dictionaries. You create the key `" key":` and the value `"this is the value"`.

```
import pandas as pd

name = 'Lisa'
location = 'USA'

exp = {
    'job': 'software engineer',
    'company':'amazon',
      'date':  '03/12',
      'job location': 'seattle',
      'description': 'worked as a software dev',
      'college': 'standford',
      'degree': 'computer science'
    }
df = pd.Series(exp)

print(f"Name: {name}, Location: {location} ")

print(df)
```

This is an example snippet of your full code.

Comment: Sure but that is not my issue and does not answer my question. My problem isn't not being able to create a dictionary. I have one. That was just a description of the lists that I have (although shown poorly) and want to join into a single panda dataframe. Its 4 list, 2 of which are dictionary list turn into a dataframe.

Comment: When I answered your question, you had =  signs in your dictionary. Even if you fixed it, that was a major problem with your code. That is why my answer did not fully answer your question

Comment: As I said, it was just a description of the list that I have. It was not my actual code and it was framed that way to show what I had vs what I wanted. It wasn't the correct way to show the dictionary but it was also not code or something that was wrong/not working in the first place or the root of any problem.